# How to draw spatial data stored in Oracle database in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle-spatial

I'm trying to implement application that draws spatial data (mostly polygons) stored in Oracle database using C#. Connection to DB is done using ODP.NET. How can i pull data from sdo_geometry and store it in some c# or .net representation and then draw it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is probably to pull it out in one of the ISO standard formats such as WKT, WKB, GML or KML and parse those.